# How to create an list of routes that come from a solution x[i,j]?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gurobi

I'm trying to create an automatic method that, through a solution `x[i,j]` obtained in my model, manages to generate an list[list] of all routes, which collects each solution `x`, in each iteration, but without duplication.

Example:

```
routes = []
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
                if x[i,j].x:
                    print(x[i,j])
                    routes.append([x[i,j]])
```

The solution obtained is the following:

```
<gurobi.Var x[0,1] (value 1.0)>
<gurobi.Var x[1,3] (value 1.0)>
<gurobi.Var x[3,0] (value 1.0)>
```

This solution is admissible, but I thought that by doing the `routes.append([x[i,j]])` the array appeared in format `routes=[[(0, 1), (1, 3), (3,0)]]`, that was the format that I would like to work, to be more simple.

Instead I get the result `[[<gurobi.Var x[0,1] (value 1.0)>], [<gurobi.Var x[1,3] (value 1.0)>], [<gurobi.Var x[3,0] (value 1.0)>]]`, that doesn't help me.

Should I do it in another format?
By the way, can you help me to create a way, for each iteration and solution, to check the `routes` first and avoid duplicate insertion of the same route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the indexes where x[i,j] is 1. The code should look something like this:

```
routes = []
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
                if x[i,j].x:
                    print(x[i,j])
                    routes.append((i,j))
```

Alternately, use Python [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) to create the list of routes:

```
routes = [(i,j) for i in range(N) for j in range(N) if x[i,j].X > 0.5]
```

And if x is a dictionary (or a Gurobi tupledict), you can simplify this to:

```
routes = [(i,j) for i,j in x.keys() if x[i,j].X > 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks @GregGlockner, it worked. I have to take a look at Python list comprehension.
By the way, it is possible to improve this method, if for each iteration and solution, check the routes first to avoid duplicate insertion of the same route?

Comment: A [Python set type](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) may do what you need.